# Finding all graphs with chromatic number greater than chromatic index.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am looking for all graphs where $\chi(G) > \chi'(G)$. Anyone has an idea how to find them? For the time being I know that $\chi(G) = \Delta(G) + 1$ and $\chi'(G) = \Delta(G)$ but i don't know how to prove it. It seems to me that these are complete graphs with even number of vertices.

Comment: Why do you think they are complete graphs with even number of vertices?

Comment: Do you know Vizing's theorem and Brooks's theorem?

Comment: Yes I tried to use both Vizing's and Brook's theorem. From Vizing's theorem I deduced x(G) = Δ(G) + 1 and X'(G) = Δ(G) and I dont know how to use Brooks to make my group of graphs more specific.

Comment: Are you assuming that your graph $G$ is connected?

Comment: I started from considering connected graphs.

Comment: Doesn't Brooks' theorem tell you that if $\chi(G)\gt\Delta(G)$ and $G$ is connected, then $G$ has to be very specific?

Comment: Yes you are right, Brooks' theorem tells me that in this case G is complete graph or an odd cycle but is that all ?

Comment: Forget about odd cycles, $\chi'(G)=\chi(G)$ if $G$ is a cycle graph.

Comment: If $G=K_n$ then $\chi(G)=n.$ What is $\chi'(K_n)$?

Comment: then χ′(Kn) is n-1 for even number of vertices and X'(Kn) is n for odd number (or maybe considering odd and even cycles ? ), but how can i prove it ?

Comment: $\chi'(K_{2n+1})$ is $\le2n+1$ by Vizing's theorem, and $\ge2n+1$ because there are $n(2n+1)$ edges and at most $n$ edges of each color. $\chi'(K_{2n})\le2n-1$ by a simple construction.

Comment: Ok now I get it, thank you for your time